# Validate repeated value of specific column

Tags: c#

I´m creating Zip file like:

```
var consultaGerente = _contexto.PDFGenerados.Where(x => x.nGerente == Gerente).ToList();
using (ZipFile fileZip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach (var i in consultaGerente)
    {
        var fileRoute = carpetaCorrecta + i.vRutaArchivo.Replace("/", "\\");
        zip.AddFile(fileRoute, "PDF");
    }
}
```

Problem is when  `i.vRutaArchivo`  is repeated it throws an error because  we can´t add two files with same name to zip . How can I validate `i.vRutaArchivo` never comes repeated?

Comment: Use a `HashSet<string>`

Comment: Bother to format your code, and ill bother to answer

Comment: can you explain how to use it? @john

Comment: David [see here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1362/hashset-csharp-with-examples)

Comment: I see it, but how can I convert  my list to string? @john

Comment: I didn't realise that you were only using the filename. Now I see that, there's a simpler way to do it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only are about the filenames, you can use LINQ to extract the corrected (replace) filename and get a distinct list.

```
var consultaGerente = _contexto.PDFGenerados
    .Where(x => x.nGerente == Gerente)
    .Select(i => i.vRutaArchivo.Replace("/", "\\"))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

using (ZipFile fileZip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach (var i in consultaGerente)
    {
        var fileRoute = carpetaCorrecta + i;
        zip.AddFile(fileRoute, "PDF");
    }
}
```